# TinyMCE in Internet Explorer does not load

Tags: internet-explorer, tinymce

My [TinyMCE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TinyMCE) init looks like this:

```
    var tinymce_advanced_options = {
        mode : "textareas",
        theme : "advanced",
        editor_deselector : "mceNoEditor",
        theme_advanced_resizing_min_width : 500,
        theme_advanced_resizing_max_width : 800,
        plugins : "autoresize,paste,preview,safari,table,contextmenu,paste,imagepopup,emotions",

        width: "800",
        button_title_map: false,
        apply_source_formatting: true,
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
        theme_advanced_buttons1: "formatselect,outdent,indent,seperator,undo,redo,separator,emotions",
        theme_advanced_buttons2: "justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,separator,bold,italic,separator,bullist,numlist,link,separator,imagepopup,table,separator",
        theme_advanced_buttons3: "preview",
        plugin_preview_width : "500",
        plugin_preview_height : "600",

        theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing : true,
        theme_advanced_blockformats : "p,h2,h3,blockquote"
    };
```

This loads fine in Firefox whereas in Internet Explorer 7, the spinner keeps spinning and never loads.

Any clues appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps an obvious suggestion, but you might want to flush IE's cache to ensure that it's not attempting to load a borked configuration.

Comment: Look for a hint at the developer console [F12].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try commenting out all lines apart from the top to first of all get something working in IE7. Then uncomment line by line to see if its any part of your configuration.

Comment: that helped. thanks.
removed all plugins and it worked.
Any idea why adding 'emotions' plugin would cause this problem in IE7?